# asp.net textbox multiline with different newline in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, newline, multiline

I have an application on asp.net and I have 2 pages with textbox controls with texmode="multiline" are as:

**at 1st page:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Rows="2" Columns="20" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

and

**at 2nd page:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

When I am writing user input text from these input texts, if user hits the "Enter" key, I have different result for each page for newline. For example user enters "John" and then hits "Enter" key and "Doe" I have different newline in .cs files of these 2 pages:

**at 1st page in .cs file txtQuestion.text equals:**

```
John\nDoe
```

**at 2nd page in .cs file txtMessage.text equals:**

```
John\r\nDoe
```

I don't know which causes this situation and I couldn't find any solution to get the same result from those inputs

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested these pages in same browser. Usually Firefox will read ENTER key to \n\r. In IE it is \n. I feel you tested these pages in diff. browsers.

Comment: Did you try removing `Rows="2" Columns="20"` from 1st page textbox or adding to 2nd page textbox markup ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both combinations

Comment: Post the markup of both text boxes that gets generated in browser.

Comment: html generated by browser:

**first one:**
<textarea name="ctl00$cpMain$txtQuestion" rows="2" cols="20" id="cpMain_txtQuestion"></textarea>

**second one:**
<textarea name="ctl00$cpMain$txtMessage"  id="cpMain_txtMessage"></textarea>